# PHP Additional if statements block first one

Tags: php, sql

I have following statements:

```
if (isset($_POST['name'])) { 
    $name = $_POST['name']; 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM patients WHERE name LIKE '{$name}' "; 
} elseif (isset($_POST['surname'])) { 
    $surname = $_POST['surname']; 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM patients WHERE surname LIKE '{$surname}' "; 
} elseif (isset($_POST['pesel'])) { 
    $pesel = $_POST['pesel']; 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM patients WHERE pesel LIKE '{$pesel}' "; 
}
```

And I have 3 search forms. But only the first one works (name). Other do not respond. How to change it?

Comment: btw you need to search about new thing - SQL injections.

Comment: learn basic programming logic. if/elseif/elseif/... chains stop being evaluated when the first "successful" match is made.

Comment: what are you trying to do? is this a compound search for several fields?

Comment: How can be the first condition met when the search field is empty?

Comment: I want to search database for name (form: name), surname(form: surname) or pesel(form: pesel). So I have 3 search fields and just 1st one (name) is working. There are no initial values, search forms are empty

Comment: do you understand the question? can you combine the fields?

Answer (score 2):

Please check if all the $_POST[] variables are not set at the same time. Because, $_POST['name'] is the first variable and if it is set, other conditions will not be checked.

Answer (score 2):

The browser will send the input field in the request, even if it's *empty*.

You cannot test whether a string is empty with `isset`. You need `!== ""` too.

Comment: O.K. now I understand the logic. Thx all for all the answers

Answer (score 1):

```
try this....  
if(isset($_POST['name'])) {  
$name = $_POST['name'];  
echo $name;  
$sql = "SELECT * FROM patients WHERE name LIKE '{$name}' ";  
}  
else if(isset($_POST['surname'])) {   
$surname = $_POST['surname'];   
echo $surname;  
$sql = "SELECT * FROM patients WHERE surname LIKE '{$surname}' ";  
}  
else if(isset($_POST['pesel'])) {  
$pesel = $_POST['pesel'];
echo $pesel;  
$sql = "SELECT * FROM patients WHERE pesel LIKE '{$pesel}' ";  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple like condition in single query

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM patients WHERE name LIKE '{$name}' OR LIKE '{$surname}' OR LIKE '{$pesel}' ";
```

Answer (score -2):

try this:

```
if(isset($_POST['name'])||isset($_POST['surname'])||isset($_POST['pesel'])) { 
    $name = $_POST['name']; 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM patients WHERE name LIKE '{$name}' or surname LIKE '{$surname}' or pesel LIKE '{$pesel}'"; 
}
```